# Salesforce with Lync Collaboration (automate meeting request generation & email)

Tags: email, integration, service-cloud-console, video

I am evaluating the possibilities of integrating Lync with Salesforce. Ideally the requirement is to engage the customer over a video chat. The Agent from the Service Console will click on a Button, say "Go to Meeting" which should automatically create a meeting request and mail the contact with the meeting URL.

We did evaluate an App 'Blue Jeans' but it required chatter to be enabled and cannot be launched via a button.

Any pointers (either an app or via customization) using Lync to engage the customers over a Video chat will be much helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You should check [Weemo](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5a11EAB) . You can Add a video chat button to any web page or mobile app and connect customers to a live video customer support call or escalate a chat session to video.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't solve you answer for video chat explicitly, but there is an offering on the AppExchange that uses a CTI adaptor with Lync to integrate with Salesforce. May be worth poking around to see if they plan on adding any video support in the future (though it may not be part of the CTI protocol).

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3sNnEAJ

The poor reviews are a bit of a misnomer, as it appears they are just people asking questions instead of actual reviews.